# Translate menu with wildcard

Tags: i18n-l10n, routes

I am creating a menu item using [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and what I want is to translate it when I am using a wildcard, because I have a multilingual site.

There is a solution, using [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)[, but it's not the best approach.

```
$items['account/edit/%'] = array(
  'title'            => t('Edit account information'),
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => array('partners_add', 2),
  'access arguments' => array('edit account in partners'),
  'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'file'             => 'inc/partners.form.inc',
);
```

Does anyone know how to translate it using the Drupal interface?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The point is moot, because the the `hook_menu` strings should not be translated at all. Your code should in fact be:

```
$items['account/edit/%'] = array(
  'title'            => 'Edit account information',
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => array('partners_add', 2),
  'access arguments' => array('edit account in partners'),
  'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'file'             => 'inc/partners.form.inc',
);
```

I quote from: http://drupal.org/node/323101:

> The Drupal 6 and 7 menu system stores menu item titles and descriptions in English. This allows the system to cache the data, but display to users using various languages on demand. For this to work, you should *not* use t() on the title or description of menu items in your hook_menu() implementation.
>
> Again, we use plain English so that the menu system can store the English text and translate as required, benefiting performance. If, instead, we use t(), the menu system would store the menu item titles and descriptions in the language of the first visitor when the menu cache was rebuilt, which would not work as a base for translations on a multilingual site.